# Is Subbasis of topology is subset of Basis always?

Tags: general-topology

I have studied definitions of Basis and Subbasis from Munkres book. I have a question that is it necessary that if a set S is element of Subbasis then it must be element of basis?

Comment: Maybe I do not understand your question but by definition a subbasis is a subset of the topology.

Comment: A topology is a basis. A subbase is a subset of a topology.

Comment: Not if you start with a fixed subbase and a fixed base. On the other hand: If $S$ is element of a subbase of some topology $\tau$ then $S\in\tau$. And for every $S\in\tau$ we can find a basis $\mathcal B$ such that $S\in\mathcal B$. Actually we could just take $\mathcal B:=\tau$ because $\tau$ is a basis of itself.

Answer (score 3):

No not necessarily, e.g. $\mathcal{S}=\{(\leftarrow, a): a \in \Bbb R\} \cup \{(a,\rightarrow), a \in \Bbb R\}$ is a subbase for the standard topology on $\Bbb R$. And $\mathcal{B}=\{(a,b): a < b, a,b \in \Bbb R\}$ is a base for that same topology, and no element of $\mathcal S$ is in $\mathcal{B}$.

But what *is* true, is that any subbase $\mathcal{S}$ for a topology generates a base $\mathcal{B}$ for the same topology, by taking all finite intersections from $\mathcal{S}$ and then $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ as an intersection of a subfamily of size 1 is just the same set. So it depends how you look at it, and how a base and subbase are related to each other.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was actually thinking same example that you took. But, I didn't think that this subbasis will create some new basis for standard topology on R.

Comment: @user677008 a space can have many subbases and many bases too, some of them related, others not so much.

Answer (score 0):

No.
Give $S = (-1,1)$ the subbase
$$\left\{ (-1,r), (r,1) : r\text{ irrational }\right\}\text{ 
and the base }\left\{ (a,b) : a,b\text{ rational} \right\}.$$